# Telegram bot and raspberry

Tags: python, bots, telegram

Well, I'm installing a system that, when I press a button for more than 5 seconds, sends me a message on the telegram. I work everything until now less than the damn bot sent me messages without putting a command or say something and so can combine with the button.

The API I am using is this https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#the-listener-mechanism
The question I have is if the bot (official telegram API) can send message without asking?

**[SOLVED]**

```
import requests
import sys

id = "IdUSer"

token = "TokenAqui"

url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage"
params = {
'chat_id': id,

'text' : str(sys.argv[1])
}

requests.post(url, params=params)
```

**Example:** `python run.py “text message”`;

Comment: It is possible. But be aware that a bot can not initialize a conversation with a person. A bot has to receive a message from a user first in order to be able to send a message to this user. After this has happened a bot can send messages to the user any time it wishes (unless it gets blocked)

Answer (score 0):

replying to your question, yes you can send message without an incoming update using sendMessage method. If you don't post any code we can't know where is the error though